# How does one package inter-dependent libraries with Conan?

Tags: conan

I have a project for which I am trying to use conan as the package manager.
The project uses a large number of libraries, most of which are self-sufficient. However, some of them depend on another library.
To give a concrete example, let's say we have a project P that requires libraries A and B. A is self contained, but B depends on A for its compilation and linking.

I can easily create the conanfile.py for library A. I can create a conanfile.txt for project P. Assuming A and B have not been build yet, I want to be able to type in P's build directory:

```
conan install ../ --build=missing
```

and have conan download, compile and install library A, THEN download compile and install library B, with B having the correct references to A.

What is the proper approach in writing the conanfile.py of B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write the package recipe for package B, you specify that it depends on A:

```
class PackageB(ConanFile):
    requires = "A/1.0@user/stable"
```

When you specify the dependencies in your project (either with a conanfile.txt or a conanfile.py), you specify as usual your dependencies. Conan handle transitive dependencies, so it knows that it has to build (or retrieve package binary if desired) package A first, and then package B.

It is typical that the build script for package B has to take into account the dependency to A. If using CMake, the solution would be using the cmake generator, and consuming the `conanbuildinfo.cmake` that has the include directories, library names, etc. for package A.

The docs specify a bit more about the syntax:
http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile.html#requirements

You can check some of the existing packages which are already managing transitive dependencies:

- ZMQ c++ wrapper, which depends on zmq, and is a very simple example as the wrapper is header only: https://www.conan.io/source/zmqcpp/4.1.1/memsharded/stable
- Boost (depends on Zlib, BZip, but conditionally, check inside the `config()` method of the conanfile): https://www.conan.io/source/Boost/1.60.0/lasote/stable
- Poco, also depends conditionally on OpenSSL, MySQLClient: https://www.conan.io/source/Poco/1.7.3/lasote/stable

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am glad conan handles the transitive dependencies like that. You give the example of cmake package B. What if it is ./configure based? Assuming it needs to be run as:
        ./configure --with-B=<B-include-dir> --with-B-libdir=<B-lib-dir>

Comment: The ConfigureEnvironment helper can generate a command line for typical configure commands, check: http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/conanfile_py.html?highlight=configureenvironment#autotools-configure-make

Comment: The ConfigureEnvironment helper did not work well in my case. I've tried it but one of the issues seemed to be that the compiler is not setup correctly, if I remember the details. I ended up passing CC=... CXX=... as trailing arguments. I did find a solution though and that is to use the self.deps_cpp_info["PackageA"].include_paths[0] for include and similarly for the library directory.

Comment: Ok, good you made it work. Did you hard-coded CC=gcc or similar, or did you use CC=self.settings.compiler? If the ConfigureEnvironment did not behave as expected, please consider opening a github issue, maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: I hardwired it. When I have more time to investigate/document why the ConfigureEnvironment helper failed for me, I will open a github issue.

Comment: Great. But not necessary to wait to have more time, better to report it soon, even without knowing why it failed, you can always expand later.

Comment: One more question before I open a github issue: How does one determine the actual compiler command? CC=self.settings.compiler will give CC=apple-clang on my Mac, which is definitely not going to work.

Comment: Yes, it might require a bit more logic, but not that much, maybe a couple of conditionals would suffice. Just open the github issue, and we could continue the conversation there, with code snippets, etc. more easily